# Is it possible to deploy a .NET 4.0 to a machine with only .NET 3.5 SP1 installed?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, app-config

I am working on a WPF application that requires .NET 4.0 to run. The machines on the enterprise are all running .NET 3.5 SP1. Is it possible to deploy the application with its .NET 4 DLLs without having to install the full .NET 4 Framework on the client machines?

There are two parts of our implementation marries us to .NET 4.0

1. The use of the Data Grid user control (this is the easiest issue to overcome).
2. The use of the enableUnsecuredResponse property for my WCF binding.

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <customBinding>
>     <binding name="CadsBinding">
>       <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
>       <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true">
>         <secureConversationBootstrap/>
>       </security>
>       <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"/>
>     </binding>
>   </customBinding>
> </bindings>
> ```

Microsoft has release the following Hot Fix: [A hotfix that enables WCF to send secured messages and to receive unsecured responses, and to send unsecured messages and to receive secured responses, is available for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493) but if I am to deploy this Hot Fix to the enterprise, I might as well do that for the .NET 4.0 Client Profile and resolve all my issues then and there.

I am aware of the .NET 4.0 Client Profile installation. What I'm trying to avoid is the need to push out the installation of the framework for just my application.

**My Current Thought:** 
It can't be done. Even if I deploy the .NET 4 DLLs that are referenced, they will still try to be handled by an older version of the CLR which won't be able to understand them.

Comment: what do you mean? how would a .NET 4 app work on a machine which doesnt have .NET 4?

Comment: @RPM1981 I'm 98% sure it can't be done, I was hoping the community could help me with that other 2%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need .NET 4, but there is the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications. It provides functionality for most client applications, including Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), and ClickOnce features. This enables faster deployment and a smaller install package for applications that target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

This is a smaller download and smaller footprint version of the framework.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Client Profile. The OP does, after all, ask "without having to install the **full** .NET 4 Framework on the client machines?"

Comment: You're right, I did only mention the FULL framework. I was aware of the difference, just didn't occur point that out.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Those DLLs depend on assemblies registered in the GAC.  Without .Net framework installed you don't get those assemblies.  Why not just deploy with an installer?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to deploy an application which was compiled against 4.0 to a machine which only contains .Net 3.5 (any version).  The 4.0 version of the runtime must be installed on the machine.

However it is possible to use Visual Studio 2010 (and 2008) to compile an assembly targeting 3.5.  This would then be deployable to a machine only having the 3.5 framework. This feature is known as multi-targeting and here is a link to a tutorial on the subject

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what features from 4.0 you use... some of them are just syntatic sugar and the compiler generates IL for that. For example, the new "dynamic" keyword uses the new Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR), which is only available as part of .net 4.0. So, if your app uses that, there's no other way than to install .net framework 4.0 in the machine
For me, the best idea would be to set in the project properties the target version to 3.5 (specified in the properties for your project in Visual Studio), and if there aren't any errors, you can follow this general
[guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd889541.aspx) to test whether the app will work or not.

Comment: In this case, why not leave the app as a .NET35 target?